# .NET 7 Blazor WebAssembly - IAuthorizationHandler not being called when policy is used

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to implement a policy-based authentication in my Blazor WebAssembly (.NET 7) application. However, when I add the `@attribute [Authorize(Policy = <some policy>)]` to a Blazor page, my custom authorization handler doesn't get called and I always get bounced back to the login page.

What's funny is that, while I can't get the .NET pipeline to call my `HandleRequirementAsync` method on pages that have a policy filter in their `Authorize` attribute, all other pages that use roles instead (i.e. have `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "some-role")]`) *do* call the `HandleAsync` method in the same class, so it would seem that I'm registering the class correctly.

I've been surfing the net for a while looking for a solution, but most people suggest that I'm either a) not registering my authorization handler for DI (which I am doing, see the code below) or b) calling .AddAuthorization too late once the controllers have already been added to the pipeline, but moving the .AddAuthorization call before .AddControllersWithViews doesn't change anything.

What I have done looks a bit like this (redacted for readability, feel free to ask for missing pieces if needed):

**Client-side Program.cs Main():**

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

// ...

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options => options.AddEmendoPolicies());

// ...

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

**Server-side Program.cs Main():**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
{
    string conn = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Main");
    options.UseMySql(conn, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(conn));
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<UserProfile, IdentityRole<int>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // ...
    });

builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, CorrectionAuthorizationHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddEmendoPolicies()); // See PolicyTypes.cs

// ...

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

// ...

app.Run();
```

**CorrectionAuthorizationHandler.cs**:

```
public class CorrectionAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsCorrectorForCompetitionRequirement>
{
    public override Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        return base.HandleAsync(context);
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsCorrectorForCompetitionRequirement requirement)
    {
        // I am putting a breakpoint on the line right under this comment
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

`IsCorrectorForCompetitionRequirement` is currently just a marker class without anything in it, but it implements `IAuthorizationRequirement`.

Finally, my **PolicyTypes** class from the Shared project:

```
public static class PolicyTypes
{
    public const string CORRECTIONS = "Corrections";

    public static AuthorizationOptions AddEmendoPolicies(this AuthorizationOptions options)
    {
        options.AddPolicy(CORRECTIONS, policy => policy.AddRequirements(new IsCorrectorForCompetitionRequirement()));

        return options;
    }
}
```

At this point I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I've wasted too much time trying to figure out a solution, so I'm hoping for help from a kind stranger.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. I had the exact same issue after upgrading to latest msal package for WebAssembly. The custom requirement code worked fine before but the handler is never invoked under `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="7.0.10" />`

I found a workaround that may also work for you. Instead of using a custom handler/requirement, I moved logic to the "RequireAssertion" method of the policy builder:

```
options.AddPolicy(nameof(Policy.IsCustomerAdmin), policy => policy.RequireAssertion(c => {.....}));
```

It seems the built-in declarations for Require[Role|Claim|Assertion|etc.] work as intended, just not the custom AuthorizationHandler<>.